# Сломался шрифт в Chrome (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome

Как видно из скрина, шрифт ужасный. Ничего перед этим не устанавливал, возможно пришло какое-то обновление. Как сделать как было изначально (как после установки системы)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ClearType наверное нужно включить или в настройках Chrome включить DirectWrite.

Answer (score 1):

У хрома есть нерешенный до сих пор баг, связанный с веб-шрифтами. Если на сайте используется веб-шрифт, например, Helvetica Neue, и у вас локально (в операционной системе) установлен этот же шрифт - могут быть проблемы с толщиной символов. Bold-шрифт становится medium'ом, а normal - light'ом.

Проблемы проявляются случайно, закономерности в их появлении я не обнаружил. На одном сайте шрифт может вести себя нормально, а на другом этот же шрифт - отображаться криво. Удаление кеша браузера не помогает. Смена пользователя не помогает.

Единственный вариант - удалить этот шрифт из операционной системы. И, если проблема будет решена - попробовать установить его снова (если он вам нужен именно в системе и настольном софте).